# Unable to build SpringBootProject from terminal i.e command line

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE.
>            Required by:
>                project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE
>   Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE.
>   Could not parse POM https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.RELEASE.pom
>   Unable to resolve version for dependency 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar'

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.learn'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: This is my build.gradle

Comment: Let take your screenshot, something is not clear.

Comment: hi can any one give solution for this